# Bad interaction between options Joined and PlotRange when using ListLogLinearPlot

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I am trying to plot data using the `ListLogLinearPlot`.

Here is my initial code:

```
 ListLogLinearPlot[{xlist, ynorm}\[Transpose], 
   PlotRange -> All, 
   Joined -> True, 
   Axes -> {0, 0}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Black}, {Black}}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Size (d,nm)", "Normalized Signal Intensity"}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 20, FontFamily -> "Arial", Black]]
```

and my result is:

[image]

Now, when I try to change the range to go from 0 to 1000 on the x-axis, the plot becomes this:

```
ListLogLinearPlot[{xlist, ynorm}\[Transpose],
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, {0.0, 1.0}}, 
  Joined -> True, 
  Axes -> {0, 0},
  PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Black}, {Black}}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Size (d,nm)", "Normalized Signal Intensity"}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 20, FontFamily -> "Arial", Black]]
```

[image]

If I remove `Joined-> True`, I get the requested plot range, but I want my plot to be joined.

```
ListLogLinearPlot[{xlist, ynorm}\[Transpose], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, {0, 1.1}}, 
  Axes -> {0, 0}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Black}, {Black}}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Size (d,nm)", "Normalized Signal Intensity"}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 20, FontFamily -> "Arial", Black]]
```

[image]

I have no idea of what is going on. I am a polymer chemist by trade and know very basic coding. All I want is to be able to import light scattering data and visualize it using Mathematica.

Edit: Thank you for all your help! I apologize for not including my x and y data lists; here they are:

xs

```
{0.4, 0.463, 0.536, 0.621, 0.719, 0.833, 0.965, 1.117, 1.294, 1.499, \
1.736, 2.01, 2.328, 2.696, 3.122, 3.615, 4.187, 4.849, 5.615, 6.503, \
7.531, 8.721, 10.1, 11.696, 13.545, 15.686, 18.166, 21.037, 24.363, \
28.214, 32.674, 37.84, 43.821, 50.748, 58.771, 68.061, 78.82, 91.28, \
105.709, 122.42, 141.772, 164.183, 190.137, 220.194, 255.002, \
295.312, 341.995, 396.058, 458.666, 531.172, 615.139, 712.379, \
824.992, 955.406, 1106.44, 1281.34, 1483.89, 1718.47, 1990.12, \
2304.72, 2669.04, 3090.96, 3579.58, 4145.44, 4800.75, 5559.64, \
6438.51, 7456.3, 8634.99, 10000.}
```

ys

```
{0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., \
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.947, 3.55, 7.16, \
10.711, 13.27, 14.293, 13.678, 11.701, 8.885, 5.849, 3.167, 1.248, \
0.246, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., \
0., 0.04, 0.136, 0.282, 0.461, 0.649, 0.817, 0.941, 0.998, 0.971, 0., \
0., 0., 0.}
```

Comment: Since it looks like your `{xlist,ynorm}` might be plausible in side, is there any chance you might edit your question to include that data? Then someone could use their MMA to try to reproduce exactly your problem and see if the could find a fix that would be far more likely to work.

Comment: we can't replicate the issue without input data. Meanwhile a work-around: Remove `Joined-.True` and post-process the output to turn `Point`s into a `Line`, e.g., `ListLogLinearPlot[{xlist, ynorm}\[Transpose], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, {0.0, 1.0}}, Axes -> {0, 0}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Black}, {Black}}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Size (d,nm)", "Normalized Signal Intensity"}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 20, FontFamily -> "Arial", Black]] /. 
 Point -> Line`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: With `PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, {0.0, 1.0}}` the `xmin` is `0`; there is no `0` on a log plot. If you change this to a positive value, does the problem go away? Or try `PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0.0, 1.0}}`

Comment: Thank you all for the help! The workaround of /.Point->Line worked well. Meanwhile, I edited the post to include my x and y values. I apologize for not doing that originally. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

A work-around:

```
ListLogLinearPlot[{xlist, ynorm}\[Transpose], 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, {0.0, 1.0}}, Axes -> {0, 0}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Black}, {Black}}, 
   Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Size (d,nm)", "Normalized Signal Intensity"}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 20, FontFamily -> "Arial", Black]] /.
  Point -> Line
```